# Do spaces between words matter while extracting entities with SpaCy?

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm using spaCy for NER task. My training data looks like below:

```
Total HDL Cholestrol <mulitple-spaces>        Photometry <multiple-spaces>          12.3 <multiple-spaces>        mg/dl <multiple-spaces>       0-45
```

(Note: Multiple spaces between words.)

I annotated each word as below:

```
Total-BTest HDL-ITest Cholestrol-LTest <mulitple-spaces>       Photometry-UTech <mulitple-spaces>        12.3-UVal  <mulitple-spaces>       mg/dl-UUnit <mulitple-spaces>      0-45-O
```

Should my test data also be in the same format (words with multiple spaces) for spacy to exactly recognize entities?

I tested the trained spacy model with below inputs:

```
Total Cholestrol <single-space>       Photometry <single-space>         56.9 <single-space>        mg/dl <single-space>           0-45
```

My model was able to recognize entities correctly in the above case. But in the below case:

```
Total Cholestrol Photometry 56.9 mg/dl 0-45
```

(Note: No multiple spaces between words)

The model was not able to recognize the entities.

My question is, Does spacy take a number of whitespaces between words also into account while training?

If so, would removing multiple spaces in the training set be a possible solution?

Comment: Spaces should not matter. https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-named-entity-recognition-using-spacy-7140ebbb3718 may help you.

Comment: @WasiAhmad The example shown in your link does not have multiple spaces between words in training set. So I think model performs well in test set which also don't have multiple spaces in between.